# How to show headings in GridView with no results

Tags: asp.net, gridview, linqdatasource

What is the best way to still show column headings on a GridView that doesn't get any records when using LINQDataSource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Matt Berseth](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/how_to_show_header_and_footer.html) has an article in which he subclasses GridView and implements this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of off the top of my head would be to fake it in the EmptyDataTemplate.

Past that you could add a new header row one of the DataBound events.